# Update recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In my fragment, I want to update my recyclerView when I select some language in my recyclerView. Now it is updated only when I move to another fragment and then return to it.

This is code of my fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_languages, container, false);
    initViews(view);
    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();
    loadLocale();
    return view;
}

protected void initViews(View view) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), null));
}

public void loadLocale() {
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString(langPref, "");
    changeLang(language);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void changeLang(String lang) {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    saveLocale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}

public void saveLocale(String lang) {
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(langPref, lang);
    editor.apply();
}

private void initializeData() {
    languages = new ArrayList<>();
    languages.add(new Languages(getString(R.string.english)));
    languages.add(new Languages(getString(R.string.russian)));
    languages.add(new Languages(getString(R.string.deutsch)));
    languages.add(new Languages(getString(R.string.romana)));
}

private void initializeAdapter() {
    LanguagesAdapter languagesAdapter = new LanguagesAdapter(languages, position -> {
        String lang = "en";
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                lang = "en";
                break;
            case 1:
                lang = "ru";
                break;
            case 2:
                lang = "de";
                break;
            case 3:
                lang = "ro";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        changeLang(lang);
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(languagesAdapter);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (myLocale != null) {
        newConfig.locale = myLocale;
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

In my method initializeAdapter i tried to write:

```
languagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

but this is doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load a new dataset to your adapter if you want to change the contents of your recycler view.

```
LanguagesAdapter languagesAdapter = new LanguagesAdapter(...);
recyclerView.setAdapter(languagesAdapter);
```

Another approach is to update the dataset object in your adapter and calling `notifyDatasetChanged`.

Comment: it won't work since you did not update your dataset. The requirement to calling notifyDatasetChanged is to update your actual dataset first.

Comment: Calling notifyDatasetChanged directly after setting a newly created adapter actually does not do anything useful but to force a redraw of the items, but with no change in data.

Comment: In case you did not notice, your recycler view is only updated once, in onCreateView. This is why your recycler view is updated only when you recreate your fragment (going to another fragment, then back). You can try to move your initializeData call to the function that gets called when you update your locale, to force a change.

Comment: thanks, but this is way also doesn t work. I think that i need to rewrite my fragment, or idk.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `languagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` call `initializeAdapter();`. Let me know if this won't work.

Comment: I called this method after recyclerView.setAdapter(languagesAdapter); and ofc that doesn t work - Recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to flip/change language when you click any language item in the recycler list view? if that's the case you have to make a new dataset that you're feeding to this list. like you changed from EN to RU then you have a list of something in RU right? feed that list of data to recycler view in the click listener and then get the list adapter from the recycler view and call languagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

I've done something similar like this in my app as well. where we have to flip language for Arabic and English view

Comment: Yes. Can you suggest your own implementation of this problem so that I can change my own? Maybe it will be useful.

Comment: posting my implementation as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

A method to setup UI elements at onCreate of activity or onViewCreated of fragment.

```
private void setupUI() {
    tvTitle.setText(R.string.language_change_activity_title);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager mStaggeredLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rvLanguageItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_language_items);
    rvLanguageItems.setLayoutManager(mStaggeredLayoutManager);
    rvLanguageItems.addItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration(35, 35, 35, 35));
    // if we have already filled data one time then just load that data

    // else request for new items
    if (getInstance().getModel() != null)
        setAdapter(getInstance().getModel()); //it gets instance of web service and take out data class and feed that to setAdapter method 
    else
        requestForLanguageList(); // this method is just for requesting language items from web but you can use local list to update from 

    // Setup refresh listener which triggers new data loading
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshFlag = true;
            requestForLanguageList(); // web api call
        }
    });
}
```

SetupUI is calling setAdapter method which fills the data and setup click listeners

```
private void setAdapter(LanguageItemsModel languageItemsModel) {
    if (refreshFlag) // this flag i used for cancel swipe to refresh
        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    // get adapter from recycler view 
    LanguageItemAdapter languageItemAdapter = (LanguageItemAdapter) rvLanguageItems.getAdapter();
    //if the adapter you got from recycler view is empty only then you fetch a new adapter other than that you just notify that data set has been changed 
    if (languageItemAdapter == null) {
        languageItemAdapter = new LanguageItemAdapter(LanguageChangeActivity.this);
        languageItemAdapter.addAll(languageItemsModel.getLanguage());
        rvLanguageItems.setAdapter(languageItemAdapter);
    } else
        languageItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    rvLanguageItems.invalidate();
    //set item click Listener for recycler view
    rvLanguageItems.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

            if (Util.hasNetworkConnection(LanguageChangeActivity.this)) {
                final LanguageItemAdapter languageItemAdapter = (LanguageItemAdapter) rvLanguageItems.getAdapter();
                //Change Language on Network as well as local
                final Language languageClickedItem = languageItemAdapter.getCurrentClickedItem(view);
                PreferenceManager preferenceManager = PreferenceManager.getInstance();
                int savedLanguageId = preferenceManager.read(LANGUAGE_ID, languageClickedItem.getLanguageId());
                if (savedLanguageId != languageClickedItem.getLanguageId()) { // only send request when user has clicked on some other language item then current set language item

                    ChangePreferenceRequestModel.getInstance().getData(LanguageChangeActivity.this, new WebServiceListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Object response, String apiName) {//Save newly changed language prefrence
                                PreferenceManager preferenceManager = PreferenceManager.getInstance();
                                preferenceManager.save(LANGUAGE_CODE, languageClickedItem.getLanguageCode());
                                preferenceManager.save(LANGUAGE_ID, languageClickedItem.getLanguageId());
                                // UpdateUI
                                languageItemAdapter.clearSelectedItems(); // clear selection from all items
                                languageClickedItem.setSelected(true); // set current item as selected
                                languageItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // redraw screen
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception error, String apiName) {
                            Util.showToast(LanguageChangeActivity.this, LanguageChangeActivity.this.getString(R.string.exception_message), true);
                        }

                    }, changePreferenceRequestParameters, true, AppConstants.getLanguagePrefrenceChangeUrl());
                }
            } else
                Util.showToast(LanguageChangeActivity.this, LanguageChangeActivity.this.getString(R.string.no_connection), true);
        }
    }));
}
```